# Struts 2 redirects - permanent redirect option? 301 vs 302

Tags: java, redirect, struts2, temporary, permanent

By default, Struts 2 "redirect" is a temporary redirect (302).  This makes sense.  However, for SEO purposes, I need to issue a permanent redirect (301).  Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServletRedirectResult](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ServletRedirectResult.html) has a `statusCode` that should work.  Try setting the `statusCode` param on your redirect result.  If you're using the Conventions plugin, something like:

```
@Result(name="success", location="/foo", type="redirect", params={"statusCode", "301"})
```

or the old style:

```
<result name="success" type="redirect">
   <param name="location">/foo</param>
   <param name="statusCode">301</param>
</result>
```

Comment: Awesome.  That works!  However, statusCode=301 gets appended to the redirected URL when I do this =(

Comment: Ok, I was able to get around the bug by subclassing org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult.  I've overridden the method protected List<String> getProhibitedResultParams() to include "statusCode".

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not work for me. I solved it with a httpheader result:

301
    /foo